# Asp.net combobox - remember indexes or values in sessions

Tags: asp.net, session

As I have problems loosing indexes after postbacks, is it beter to remember indexes or values in sessions?

Thanks.

Comment: the problem is, in the first place, why do lose index. you should work on it. post some code

Comment: As far as i remember viewstate property can be used to remember the combobox selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say store them in sessions, HOWEVER, do you make any selection stuff in the page load event, if so, have you checked so that it won't redo that population after a postback??

This could mess things up, this would set the time on every postback:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

This would however have your stuff remain intact in the viewstate and the time would only update if the page is loaded without a postback:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Page.IsPostBack != true)
        {
            Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was filling comboboxes in pageload unconditionally. And I'm losing indexes on postback. Do you think I will solve problem if I'm binding comboboxes only when postback !=flase? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, otherwise your combobox filling will occur on each and every postback and that will mess up your indexes. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think if you simply make sure `EnableViewState` is not set to `false` for that specific control or on page level, then you will be able retain the indexes for selection done by user

Comment: Viewstate is enabled by default unless you set it in the page properties and then only retain viewstate for certain controls, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: yes, that is right. but if is set to false, then you have to remove it or make it enable